# Data not visible in ComboBox drop down

Tags: excel, vba

When I run this code, my `ComboBoxes` are populated, but do not display the data

I created a single ComboBox userform, and it worked fine. When i added additional `Textboxes`, it stopped displaying the data, even though it was populated.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For i = 1 To 10
        cboRaceNum.AddItem i
        cboHorseNum.AddItem i
    Next i

End Sub
```

I can drop down the box, not see the data, but can select a blank line, and the selected data appears in the `ComboBox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Seems like somehow your data is aligned from the Right**. Below code should work.

**Try :**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        cboRaceNum.TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
        cboHorseNum.TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft

    For i = 1 To 10
        cboRaceNum.AddItem i
        cboHorseNum.AddItem i
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeff ... Glad it Worked. Accept & Upvote the Answer :)